# Accessing GEE cloud project from Google Colab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, google-earth-engine

I am having some issues accessing my GEE cloud project from google colab python API.

I am following the google guide, I first login so that I can make authenticated requests to Google Cloud. **This first step works**.

`PROJECT = 'my-project' !gcloud auth login --project {PROJECT}`

and then download a private key file. **This step doesn't work**

`SERVICE_ACCOUNT='foo-name@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com' KEY = 'my-secret-key.json' !gcloud iam service-accounts keys create {KEY} --iam-account {SERVICE_ACCOUNT}`

I might be making a mistake in replacing the values in the code example.